# Retrieve contact info

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I need retrieve detailed contact info from my LinkedIn profile. I can get the basic profile information with this code:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($li_api_key, $li_secret_key); $oauth->setToken($li_oauth_key, $li_oauth_secret);

$params = array(); 
$headers = array(); 
$method = OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET;

$query = "?format=json"; 
$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" . $query;

$oauth->fetch($url, $params, $method, $headers); 
$information = $oauth->getLastResponse();
```

I also tried some additional parameters in the URL's query string, but that did not work:

```
$query = "?format=json&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress";
$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" . $query;
```

But I also need the email, phone, website and street address. How can I get this additional information?

Answer (score 2):

By default, LinkedIn only grants access to your basic profile. For full profile fields, you need to add scope=r_fullprofile to your request. See here for more information: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting

Comment: As of my experience even though you get the full profile access it still throw  "Unknown field {contact} in resource {Person}" error